# Equivalence of elements in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I was wondering about the formal definition of equivalence in a ring. When exactly are two elements $a, b$ in a ring $A$ equal? It seems to me that the existence of an equivalence relation on the set $A$ is implicit in the definition of a ring (or of a group).

Now my question: Is there a nice characterization for such an equivalence of elements?

Comment: your question is not clear. two elements are equal if their difference is zero. what you mean by equivalence? equal and equivalence could be two different things.

Comment: Well, two elements are equal if their difference is *equal to* zero. What does *equal to zero* actually mean?

Comment: it means that addition map, maps a and -b to zero.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about using a ring here: you are apparently just asking what the definition of two elements of a set being equal means, and just using the underlying set of a ring as an example.

Ultimately you would fall back to [the ZFC axiom](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#1._Axiom_of_extensionality) that determines when two sets are equal, since members of sets are also themselves sets. This definitively tells you when two members of a set are equal.

Answer (score 0):

If $A=R/I$ the quotient ring of $R$ modulo an ideal $I$, then $a+I=b+I$ if and only $a-b\in I$.

Any ring $R$ can be thought of as $R/(0)$ hence $a=b$ if and only if $a-b=0$.